# Error: cannot find symbol - Internal Search Engine

Tags: java, compiler-errors, search-engine

I need to create an internal search engine that access a Server File, and looks through each text file for the keyword/phrase that the client needs. However, with the code I have so far i keep getting this error:

> SearchFunction.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>           } while (fileName == true); 
>                    ^   symbol:   variable fileName   location: class SearchFunction
> ```

Any help at all would be awesome! Thanks!

```
public class SearchFunction{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        try{
            do {
                int count = 1;
                String fileName = "Buyerserver" + count + "Log.txt";

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (fileName));

                int linecount = 0;
                    String line;
                System.out.println("Searching for " + args[0] + " in file...");

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    linecount++;
                    int indexfound = line.indexOf(args[0]);

                    if (indexfound > -1){
                        System.out.println("Word was found at positon " + indexfound + " on line " + linecount);
                        }
                    }
                    br.close();
                    count++;
                } while (fileName == true); 
            } 
            catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("IO Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a complicated task and you are still missing some basic Java concepts and debugging skills. I think you should slow down.

Comment: use solr instead, it will sort out your problems

Comment: as @SotiriosDelimanolis u r missing the basic java. u should start reading some java books or something before accepting to develop a java file.... but here is the problem. fileName is inside the loop. it should be defind outside (just before do). also (fileName is string, you can't compare it to true. you possibly want to check if the file exists?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `fileName==true`? You're evaluating a String to a boolean, I don't think is what you intended. Also you want to accomplish an elaborated task with poor java knowledge. I strongly suggest you to run through some java tutorial before starting with something like this.

Comment: Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
String fileName
```

is declared inside the loop, but you want to test it in the loop condition, where it isn't visible.

As a rule of thumb, variables are visible within the block where they are declared, after they are declared.

For example,

```
if (x=0) // doesn't compile, x is not in scope here...
{
   x=1; // doesn't compile, x is not in scope here...
   int x;
   x=2; // ok
}
```

That said, the idea of writing your own search engine, especially as a beginner, is very questionable.

By the way, fileName will never be `true`, so you must fix the while condition, too.

Comment: +1 - A brief sentence or two about **variable scope** would make this answer better.

Comment: @Rudi ok, expanded my answer